# Problem of importing pure ESM module with only exports in jest tests

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest, babel-jest

I think there were some problems with jest loading pure esm modules previously, as seen in [#11373](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/11373) and [#9771](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/9771). According to the release, I think jest should now support this kind of issue after version 28.0.0. However, I still got the issue similar to the one in #11373. I use the latest jest version. Do I need to do something else to fix this issue? I cannot find any further answers to it since the post suggest the package should have supported it and I do not need to do any other things. Here's my config:
package.json:

```
"main": "./dist/src/index.js",
 "types": "./dist/src/index.d.ts",
 "files": [
    "dist/src",
    "!dist/**/*.map"
  ],
  "type": "module"
"dependencies":{
  "jest": "^29.1.2"
}
```

jest.config.js:

```
export default {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  testRegex: '/tests/.*\\.(test|spec)?\\.(ts|tsx|js)$',
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'node'],
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules', '<rootDir>/dist'],
};
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "ES2020",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "ES2015",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictBindCallApply": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  }
}
```

I also attempted to set the jest resolver to the enhanced-resolver in one of their embedded link, but I got an error of `Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module <rootPath>\resolver.js from <rootPath>\node_modules\jest-resolve\build\resolver.js not supported`